# For Loop In JavaScript Table

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to do a for in in an obj Json array looking for a variable, specify the following example. Thank you very much in advance.
I want to consult which division a certain team is in "Vasco".
I wanted to understand what better way.

{"table":{"1° Division":["Flamengo","Goiás","Palmeiras"], "2° Division": ["Real","Barc","Madri"], "3°Division": ["Vasco","Itunbi","Recife"]}}

Comment: It’s `Object.keys(yourObject.table).find((key) => yourObject.table[key].includes("Vasco"))`. Get familiar with [how to access and process objects, arrays, or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212), how to [access properties](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), and use the static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Answer (score -1):

if you treat the json as an array it should come easy for you.
after that you can use a shorting algorithm